# Drupal: sending 1500 emails monthly

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to enable a mailing list on a website and I was considering to use Simplenews module for it.

I have to send approximately 1500 e-mails per month. I was considering if it is a huge emails amount for drupal and simplenews module and I should use another service, or not.

thanks

Comment: 1500 emails per month is a 2 mails per hour and this is not a BIG amount of emails

Comment: We're talking about newsletters here. You don't trickle them out over the course of the month - you want everybody to have it in their inbox at the same time. The rate will be 0/h for 99% of the month and then 1500 emails at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit II: The Edit Wars** - I've just read what SimpleNews provides and see that it *is* a newsletter sender. Skip the next edit and go straight onto the last block.

---

**Edit: The Phantom Edit**  - My answer is in the understanding that by mailing list, you meant newsletter. I see now that you could just mean a forum-by-email (like many open source projects operate, for example).

If it's the second, you're probably fine just sending it yourself. Sending a couple of dozen emails to each user at once isn't going to kill your box and hopefully won't get you labelled as a spammer.

If it's the first and you're sending 1500 emails at once for marketing interest, read on.

---

I would always argue for a third party service for mailing list - especially if your make money from people actioning these emails.

Why? Because it's so easy to get blocked as a spammer (even for legitimate emails) if you send enough email. By using a third party, it's their job to deal with making sure your IP (with them) remain's unblocked and trusted by all the major players in the spam-scanning world.

It certainly costs more than doing it yourself but with a lowish volume like 1.5k/month, you're probably not looking at that much money.

I use [iContact](http://www.icontact.com/affordable-email-marketing/) for a client and they've been just great. They have fairly detailed reporting as well (so do lots of email companies) which their marketing bods love. Would cost you $25/month for your volumes.

Comment: At 1500/month, the big mail providers won't even notice. It's like spitting in the ocean :)

Comment: On the other hand, if they provide this service to multiple clients (which is likely), the content that all their clients are sending has to remain trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

1500 emails is not that many (assuming you meen total emails, not emails which are then sent to 100,000 users), simplenews looks like it is activly maintained and has a large userbase, so shouldn't be a problem.

Just as an asside, SO is probably not the best place to ask for module reviews try using [drupal modules](http://drupalmodules.com/module/simplenews) if you would like oppinions of  modules.

Answer (score 0):

1500 is well within the range of what Drupal can handle.